# peformClick() on an AlertDialog in an InstrumentationTestCase2 doesn't work

Tags: android, multithreading, automated-tests, android-alertdialog

I want to click on an `AlertDialog` in an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. But the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` execute, after the test finished and not during the test (I know that, because I debugged this test).

My test checks a delete button. If the delete button is pressed, an `AlertDialog` will appear and ask the user again. If the user accepts the `AlertDialog`, the database row will be deleted.

```
public class ShiftTest2 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Shift> {

  @UiThreadTest
  public void testDeleteButton() {
      Shift shift = getActivity();
      Button deleteButton = (Button) shift.findViewById(R.id.shift_delete);

      deleteButton.performClick(); // That works fine

      AlertDialog alertDialog = shift.getAlertDialog();

      // The thread execute the performClick() after this test finished
      alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();

      final Bundle savedShift = mDb.getShiftById("1");
      assertNull(savedShift); // This assert fail
  }
}
```

The `OnClickListener` for my delete button.

```
public void onDeleteButton(View view) {
    if (mDeleteDialog != null) {
        mAlert = mDeleteDialog.create();
        mAlert.show();
    }
}
```

And here the listeners for my `AlertDialog`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...

    mDeleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mDeleteDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_shift_really));

    mDeleteDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.delete), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            mDb.deleteShift(mId);
            resetAllPreferences();

            Intent parentActivity = new Intent(context, WorkingTimeSettings.class);
            startActivity(parentActivity);
        }
    });

    mDeleteDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Nothing to do here
        }
    });
}
```

I tried `Thread.sleep(10000)` already in the test, but it changes nothing. The problem is, that the thread don't jump out of the test to execute the positive button listener. Perhaps because of the `@UiThreadTest` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem myself. It was really the `@UiThreadTest` annotation. Just run the *critical* parts in the method `shift.runOnUiThread()`.

```
public void testDeleteButton() {
    final Shift shift = getActivity();
    final Button deleteButton = (Button) shift.findViewById(R.id.shift_delete);

    final int deleteButtonViewMode = deleteButton.getVisibility();
    assertEquals(View.VISIBLE, deleteButtonViewMode);

    shift.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            deleteButton.performClick();
            shift.getAlertDialog().getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
        }
    });
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    final Bundle savedShift = mDb.getShiftById("1");
    assertNull(savedShift);
}
```

Hint: I have removed the annotation for all other tests, too. Otherwise they would not be green.